# C++ Template Unresolved Error

Tags: c++

I am recently working on a template linked list, however I have encounered a problem

```
    #ifndef _T_NODE_
#define _T_NODE_
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class TNode{
public:
    TNode();
    TNode(T a);

    ~TNode();

private:
    T template_;
    TNode<T> *link_;
};

#endif
```

My implementation is:

```
template<typename T>
TNode<T>::TNode(){
    link_ = NULL;
    template_ = T();
}

template<typename T>
TNode<T>::TNode(T a){
    template_=a;
    link_ = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
TNode<T>::~TNode(){
    delete link_;
}
```

In another Class, I tried to referred it in a function as such:

```
TNode<Bike> * actPtr;
        actPtr = new TNode<Bike>(a);
```

I receive the following error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TNode<class Bike>::TNode<class Bike>(class Bike)"  referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
```

Comment: Is implementation in file that is included by another Class?

Comment: No, it only #include "TNode.h"